# CURL get 500 error after 40 seconds

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I set all options with timeout and set_time_limit, but it's not help. CURL get 500 error after 40 seconds. On remote server start long process and I need a wait finish. If file is small - all ok, if file is big - get 500 error after 40 seconds. This my code:

```
$curl = curl_init("http://example.com/index.php?page=uploads");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $datas = array(
        "id" => $id,
        "video" => $filename->new_file_name,
        "title" => $_POST["title"],
        "description" => $_POST["description"],
        "category" => array($_POST["category"]),
        "location" => $_POST["location"],
        "check" => $check,
        "start" => $start,
        "duration" => $duration
    );
    $data = json_encode($datas);

    $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 900000);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, curl_exec, 0);
    curl_exec($curl);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: You should check at your server side there error since HTTP error 500 means "internal server error".

Comment: Do you use correct url (http://example.com/index.php?page=uploads)?

Comment: Yes, it's correct url. Script on remote server is start. Remote script get command by curl, parse POST, start convert file... The file is converted and saved in the folder. The logs are no errors. Script successfully completed on remote server. But curl 40 seconds after start give me 500 error. But CURL must get success message about finish. It turns like disconnection. And it always 40 seconds...

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old and the poster likely isn't having the same issue but:

To troubleshoot HTTP 500 errors read over your apache error log file.

If you are receiving an HTTP500 after 40s then likely the error in your log file is "mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds" which is resolved not by increasing your PHP Execution Timeout but increasing FcgidIOTimeout which defaults to 40 seconds.

http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidiotimeout

This can be done by adding / modifying the following line your fcgid.conf file.

```
FcgidIOTimeout 120
```

Comment: For me, this was the correct answer. For CENTOS / RHE (7), you can find fcgid.conf here: /etc/httpd/conf.d. I need to add the following line to solve the Internal Server Error: FcgidIOTimeout 300

Answer (score 0):

A `HTTP500` error indicates that there is a SEVER side error.

Check the web server(Apache?) or application server(Php?) logs in order to be able to debug the issue.

HTTP500 status explained: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html

Comment: Script on remote server is start. Remote script get command by curl, parse POST, start convert file... The file is converted and saved in the folder. The logs are no errors. Script successfully completed on remote server. But curl 40 seconds after start give me 500 error. But CURL must get success message about finish. It turns like disconnection. And it always 40 seconds...